# To detect number of times app opens

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I need to `count` the `total app opens` in `Ionic 3` app. Which `event` should I use for that? I know that I have to do that on `app.component.ts` file. But which `event` should I use? We cannot use `page lifecycle hooks` on `app component`. So if I use `constructor` then it works only once since it won't fire again. So what then?

Comment: In the app or in backend ? - per user or per device ?

Comment: In the app and per user. @split